# How to send an array of strings using WebRequest

Tags: c#, post, webrequest

I have a method in my controller that accepts an array of strings:
`public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostData(string[] data)`

The thing I want to send a request using a console app to my api, but Im getting a 404 response and its not reaching the controller:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1119/api/psr");
request.Method = "POST";
string num= "[ \"89\",\"21\" , \"2A,\" ]";

                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(num);

                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

                dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is correct(including port number) and that the controller method is marked to accept post methods via the `[HttpPost]` attribute? I also see that you specified `PostData` as the method but your URL contains `api/psr`.

Comment: it is correct, and already sending data from webapps

Comment: perhaps you can use fiddler and compare the request you are sending via the console application to the request of the web page. This might indicate  to what is wrong.

Comment: I think the way I am sending the array is wrong

Comment: You are missing a comma after `\"21\"`, try "[ \"89\",\"21\", \"2A\" ]"

Comment: no, thats not the issue, it was missing only here

Comment: Do you have to be authenticated to get to your controller?

Comment: can you post your controller code?